# Simple websocket tutorial app not recieving 'chat' events despite being connected

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, cloud9-ide

I am following along with a tutorial which demonstrates how to set up a very simple chat app with nodejs (express) and WebSockets. I can confirm that the connection between client and server is established but cannot figure out why the 'chat' event does not get processed by the server on the other side. I am using Socket.io 2.04 and my server is running out of Cloud9.  I am just trying to get a working example set up so I have the CSS, HTML, and script in the same file for the webpage. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I've spent enough hours fiddling with this that I could really use some expert advice...

```
    // server side code

        var express =require("express");
        var app = express();

        var socket = require('socket.io');

        var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

        app.use(bodyParser.json());

        app.use(function(req, res, next) {
          res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
          next();
        });

        app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

       app.get("/websockets", function(req, res) {
       res.render("websockets.ejs");
});


var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING!");
});

// Socket setup 
var io = socket(server);


io.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);

    // Handle chat event
    socket.on('chat', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
    });

});
```

and below is the page sent to the client

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>WebSockets 101</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>


        <style>
                        body{
                font-family: 'Nunito';
            }

            h2{
                font-size: 18px;
                padding: 10px 20px;
                color: #575ed8;
            }

            #mario-chat{
                max-width: 600px;
                margin: 30px auto;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
                border-radius: 2px;
            }

            #chat-window{
                height: 400px;
                overflow: auto;
                background: #f9f9f9;
            }

            #output p{
                padding: 14px 0px;
                margin: 0 20px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
                color: #555;
            }

            #feedback p{
                color: #aaa;
                padding: 14px 0px;
                margin: 0 20px;
            }

            #output strong{
                color: #575ed8;
            }

            label{
                box-sizing: border-box;
                display: block;
                padding: 10px 20px;
            }

            input{
                padding: 10px 20px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background: #eee;
                border: 0;
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                background: #fff;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
                font-family: Nunito;
                font-size: 16px;
            }

            button{
                background: #575ed8;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 18px;
                border: 0;
                padding: 12px 0;
                width: 100%;
                border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

       <div id="mario-chat">
           <div id="chat-window">
               <div id="output"></div>
           </div>
           <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Handle"/>
           <input id="message" type="text" placeholder="Message"/>
           <button id="send">Send</button>
       </div>


        <script>
                   // Make connection
            var socket = io.connect('https://mywebsitename:8080');

// Query DOM
var message = document.getElementById('message'),
      handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
      btn = document.getElementById('send'),
      output = document.getElementById('output');

// Emit events
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  socket.emit('chat', {
      message: message.value,
      handle: handle.value
  });
  message.value = "";
  console.log("It should have sent out a chat event...");
});

// Listen for events
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are connecting to `https://mywebsitename:8080`, but your server code does not show an `https` server.  It only shows an `http` server.

Comment: Since I am hosting the site on cloud9, any URL will have an https (I think...). Just to be sure, I tried connecting to http://mywebsitename:8080 instead and got the same result but with the added client-side error of "mixed content." In any case, if that were the problem I would not expect the socket connection to be established in the first place (which it is). As an added FYI here is the console output from my Cloud9 IDE: "SERVER IS RUNNING!
made socket connection EQD3s1EojwJHrgfuAAAA"

Comment: I don't see anything obvious.  I'd say look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger at the detailed webSocket packets for the socket.io connection and see if you see what you expect to be coming and going from the browser.